# Split an Arraylist into multiple lists for a same element (String) - JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, split

I have an ArrayList of similar objects. I have to split the lists into multiple lists based on a similar element (String)

This is an example, the ArrayList have inside objects, not (String, Integer)

Here is the sample List:

```
ArrayList{ {'Milk', 12}, {'Apple', 60}, {'Coffe', 87}, {'Pear', 39}, {'Coffe', 87}, 
           {'Milk', 99}, {'Apple', 43}, {'Milk', 20} }
```

Result should be:

List 1:

```
ArrayList{ {'Milk', 12}, {'Milk', 99}, {'Milk', 20} }
```

List2:

```
ArrayList{ {'Apple', 60}, {'Apple', 43} }
```

List3:

```
ArrayList{ {'Coffe', 87}, {'Coffe', 87} }
```

List4:

```
ArrayList{ {'Pear', 39} }
```

Somebody would to give me a easier way doing this??

Comment: Post the code you have tried. At least the data structures involved. What is `{'Milk', 12}`? A Map? An object? An array? What are the types? String? Double? BigDecimal? Integer? MyAwesomeNumber?

Comment: This is a Object, then this is a ArrayList of Objects

Comment: This doesn't answer any of the question in the comment above =/.

Comment: Sorry because I have not code, because I don't know how do it

Comment: I don't understand the reason to give negative feedback to this question because I ask when I don't know how to do this function and that is why I wrote this question......

Comment: We expect for you to give it a shot before asking for a solution on SO. Google is full of tutorials about Java object structures and libraries you can use to pluck and object this way.

Comment: I searched and found nothing to solve my problem with Strings because I seek a function, not a library. I do not want to add a new library in my program, I just want a function to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Multimaps` from `com.google.common.collect` package

example

```
List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>entries=...
Map<String,Collection<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>>map=Multimaps.index(entries,new GroupFunction()).asMap();

class GroupFunction implements Function<Map.Entry<String,Integer>, String> {
    @Override
    public String apply(Map.Entry<String,Integer>input) {
        return input.getKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where I could download this library?

Answer (score 1):

Following is the code which splits the arraylist based on a string in an object -

Assuming the Sampleobject.class to be -

```
 public class SampleObject implements Comparable<SampleObject> {

    String name;
    String value;

    SampleObject(String name, String value) {
        setName(name);
        setValue(value);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SampleObject o) {
        return (this.name).compareTo(o.name);
    }
}
```

Main Class SplitArray.class -

```
    public class SplitArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

        List<SampleObject> list = new ArrayList<SampleObject>();

        list.add(new SampleObject("Milk", "12"));
        list.add(new SampleObject("Apple", "60"));
        list.add(new SampleObject("Coffe", "87"));
        list.add(new SampleObject("Pear", "39"));
        list.add(new SampleObject("Coffe", "87"));
        list.add(new SampleObject("Milk", "99"));
        list.add(new SampleObject("Apple", "43"));
        list.add(new SampleObject("Milk", "20"));
        list.add(new SampleObject("Milk", "20"));

        System.out.println(splitArrayByName(list));
    }

    private static List<List<SampleObject>> splitArrayByName(List<SampleObject> list) {

        List<List<SampleObject>> masterList = new ArrayList<List<SampleObject>>();
        List<SampleObject> uniqueList = new ArrayList<SampleObject>();

        Collections.sort(list);
        uniqueList = removeDuplicates(list);
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int childListIndex = 0;

        for (SampleObject element : uniqueList) {
            for (i = j; i < list.size(); i++) {

                if (element.compareTo(list.get(i)) == 0) {
                    if (masterList.size() == 0) {
                        masterList.add(new ArrayList<SampleObject>());
                    }
                    if (masterList.size() >= 1) {
                        masterList.get(childListIndex).add(list.get(i));
                    }
                    j++;
                } else {
                    masterList.add(new ArrayList<SampleObject>());
                    childListIndex++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return masterList;
    }

    private static List<SampleObject> removeDuplicates(List<SampleObject> list) {

        List<SampleObject> uniqueList = new ArrayList<SampleObject>();
        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

        for (SampleObject sampleObject : list) {
            if (!set.contains(sampleObject.getName())) {
                uniqueList.add(sampleObject);
                set.add(sampleObject.getName());
            }
        }
        return uniqueList;
    }
}
```